# Orthonormal basis and unit vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $S$ be an orthonormal  basis for $\mathbb R^n$. If $v \in \mathbb R^n$ is a unit vector, then is $(v)_S$ also a unit vector? Not very clear how to prove this.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this helps.

Take $S=\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ an orthonormal basis, then for any vector $v\in\mathbb R^n$ we have scalars $c_1,\ldots, c_n$ such that $v=c_1v_1+\ldots+c_nv_n$. Notice that

$$||v||^2=\langle v,v\rangle=\langle c_1v_1+\ldots+c_nv_n,c_1v_1+\ldots+c_nv_n\rangle$$

We can expand the latter due to bilinearity of inner product and remember that $\langle v_i,v_j\rangle=0$ whenever $i\neq j$ due to orthogonality of basis. Thus

$$||v||^2 = c_1^2||v_1||^2+\ldots+c_n^2||v_n||^2$$

And due to normality (not sure if that's a word)

$$||v||^2 = c_1^2+\ldots+c_n^2$$